# How can I pass HTTP url using parameter which is having split function also in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In logic app I have one HTTP connector where I'm passing filter using split operation.

When I tried to use all url from parameter it throws error - format not correct.

Previously it was working like this when I pass complete url

```
"HTTP": {
                  "type": "Http",
                  "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "https://demo.api.com/getcustomers?$format=json&$filter=dateForSystem eq '@{split(body('Get_MaxDateTime')?['keyValue'],' ')[0]}'&$skip=@{variables('DemoVariable')}",
                    "headers": {
                    }
                  },
                  "runAfter": {
                    "Set_variable_AccessToken": [
                      "Succeeded"
                    ]
                  }
                }
```

I want to parameterised the uri so I created a parameter like this and
used it is not working.

```
"HTTP": {
                  "type": "Http",
                  "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "uri": "[parameters('HTTPuri')]/getcustomers?$format=json&$filter=dateForSystem eq '@{split(body('Get_MaxDateTime')?['keyValue'],' ')[0]}'&$skip=@{variables('DemoVariable')}",
                    "headers": {
                    }
                  },
                  "runAfter": {
                    "Set_variable_AccessToken": [
                      "Succeeded"
                    ]
                  }
                }


                  "parameters": {
    "HTTPuri": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://demo.api.com/"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your wrong way to reference the parameter. The correct format should be `@{parameters('HTTPuri')}`.

[image]

[image]